# Site performance decreased after changing varchar to nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-performance

I recently had to convert one of the table's column definition to `nvarchar` from `varchar`. Since that, I can feel that the searching data thru the table has became slower.

I have like 4200000+ rows in the table and growing.

My web app doesn't currently use stored procedures to retrieve data from the database. If I use stored proc, will it slightly improve the searching performance?

Or is there any other advice you'd give for improvement?

Here is the query currently used now:

```
SELECT TOP 100 id, callerID, dateTime, activity, senderNum, msgSent, smsgRespond, msgIn 
FROM tbl_activitylog 
WHERE callerID = @callerID 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

The column `msgSent` is the one which was converted to nvarchar.

Below is the table structure:

```
id (int, Primary Key, Auto Increment)  
callerID (bigint)  
dateTime (datetime)  
activity (varchar(50)  
senderNum (int)  
msgSent (nvarchar(160))  
smsgRespond (varchar(50))  
msgIn (varchar(160))
```

I do not understand the index part.

Comment: Post your query, show your table structure, show your indexes, and show the query plan for your query.

Comment: First of all - going to `nvarchar` has basically **doubled** the space your string columns take up; more data -> more time needed to move stuff around. Nothing you can do about that. Second: **no** - just changing to a stored procedure will not really help; you need to tune your query and see if you can speed it up by means of adding appropriate indexes.

Comment: I did not know about the indexing part so I guess I didn't do any index in the database. Is it possible to do now in the database?

Comment: Yes sure - you need to learn things like measuring performance (SQL Server Profiler) and you need to learn about indexing (how and when) - you can always add those later on, no problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I did not know about the indexing part so I guess I didn't do any index in the database.

The number one most important thing when dealing with database performance is **INDEXES**.

Add an [index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) on `(callerID, id DESC)`.

Your query will be much, *MUCH* faster.

You can also run your query in SSMS, and press the "Estimated query plan" and it will most likely come with a missing index warning. You can practically copy and paste this warning and just run it. The only thing you need to change is the name of the index.

Comment: I just checked in the SSMS and I found that that is already an index in the table. Its for the id column and its clustered.

So should I create another index for `callerID` and `id`? And what kind of cluster type should I choose?

And how do I improve my query to make use of the index?

Comment: Yes you should. It need not be clustered. There can be only one clustered index per table. Check if you are getting an activity log by ID anywhere in the codebase, if you never get an activitylog based on Id then you can cluster it on your index and remove the id cluster

Comment: @YeMyatAung: You're making it more complicated than it needs to be. Try this: 1) Type in your query in SSMS. 2) Press 'Show estimated query plan'  3) Select 'Show Missing Index'. 4) Copy and paste it what it says you should do. 5) Change the index name to something valid and meaningful. 6) Run it. That's all you need to do. You don't need to change your query. Also, get a book on SQL Server and read it. It doesn't make any sense to try to optimize your database performance until you understand what indexes are and how to use them.

Comment: @MarkByers Got it :D

Sorry for bothering you somehow :)

Comment: I hope you take also the last part of the recommendation - READ A BOOK.

Comment: @YeMyatAung If you don't get a book, check this for a start: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Putting your query into a stored procedure don't bring you automatically better performance.
So if you can retrieve all the data you need with "simple SELECT statements", do it like this.

But you should check and eventually repair your database.

```
DBCC CHECKDB('<db_name>') -- check the db for error
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE('<db_name>') -- fix errors
```

Also important create relevant indexes!

EDIT: AS you post your query after: Add index on CalledId.

Check your SQL SELECTS, check what columsn you have in your WHERE statements and add indexes for them. This should improve a lot!

Comment: I don't think a statement like this is accurate - just because you use a stored procedure isn't *normally slower* - what makes you say that? Seems like a rather unqualified statement to me ....

Comment: Well everything needs to be processed. Put a simple SELECT * FROM tbl, and put the same inside a SP, so there are more steps todo for the database, so why you think there is no time difference in executing those two then?

Comment: Because both - a standalone SQL query and a stored procedure - basically have to go through the same process of being parsed, a "good enough" query plan needs to be determine, then executed, and the results returned. Just by putting it into a stored procedure doesn't make that process slower! Also: if you execute the query again, chances are the stored procedures will actually be **faster** since it will cache its query execution plan, while a new query will have to go through all the steps of the process again

Comment: Well you right, it is always not black & white :) I will edit my post and modify it due the fact the main goal for the answer was that he won't win anything to just put his SQL query into a SP.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an index against `varchar` and query contains `Nvarhchar` then such index will be ignored. You need to sync all types used (the same everywhere) and **rebuild the index**, e.g.:

```
ALTER INDEX IX_msgSent ON tbl_activitylog REBUILD
```